# Ill-formed constraint expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Regarding function `f`, is the substituted constraint expression of the non-type template argument
of templated variable `b` a valid constant expression? Which specific wording of the C++20 standard
either allows or forbids this?

```
struct s { static constexpr bool v = true; };
template<auto> inline constexpr bool b = true;
constexpr bool f(auto x) requires b<x.v> { return true; }
static_assert(f(s{})); // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc ok
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/xhdGPbhx3)

---

The error message from GCC:

```
<source>:3:36: error: missing template arguments before '<' token
    3 | constexpr bool f(auto x) requires b<x.v> { return true; }
      |                                    ^
<source>:3:36: error: expected initializer before '<' token
<source>:4:15: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
    4 | static_assert(f(s{}));
      |               ^
```

Comment: note that `constexpr bool f(auto x) requires b<decltype(x)::v> { return true; }` is fine with all of them. And I don't understand why yours is ok for clang / msvc, but thats probably just my ignorance about c++20

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77440394/567292

Answer (score 3):

The reason this code is correct is that non of the wording in [[expr.const]p5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5) applies:

> An expression *E* is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of *E*, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - [...]

And none of the proceeding points apply. Since `x.v` does not apply an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `x`, and `S::v` is a constant expression which you can apply an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on, `x.v` (when `x` is of type `S` and is not a reference) is a constant expression.

---

It looks like gcc is trying to parse `b<x.v>` as `(b < x.v) >` (as two relational operators), and so giving you an error. This is clearly a bug, as `b<` should be a template no matter what since `b` is a templated entity.

More examples of this gcc bug happening: https://godbolt.org/z/fP74hW1qs https://godbolt.org/z/19K4nYTjT

If you use the `noexcept` specifier instead of `requires` you get an interesting additional error message:

https://godbolt.org/z/8xqre5bbT (https://godbolt.org/z/cPYbb6vsq for trailing return type)

```cpp
<source>:3:38: error: use of parameter outside function body before '.' token
    3 | constexpr bool f(auto x) noexcept(b<x.v>) { return true; }
      |                                      ^
```

Which makes me think at some point naming function parameters outside of the function body makes GCC error out but the warnings aren't well written when it's inside a `requires`.

Comment: GCC issue reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112448