# Invalid type conversion of non-type template argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I would expect that `x` can be used used as converted constant expression of type `bool`, because of the user-defined conversion-operator `constexpr operator bool() const`. However, GCC and MSVC reject this code while Clang seems to accept it. Should the code be legal according to the C++20 standard?

```
template<bool B>
struct s { constexpr operator bool() const { return B; } };
constexpr auto f(auto x) -> s<x> { return {}; }
static_assert(f(s<true>{})); // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/o4jvWr83s)

---

The error message from GCC:

```
<source>:3:32: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    3 | constexpr auto f(auto x) -> s<x> { return {}; }
      |                                ^
<source>:3:32: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:3:32: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:3:32: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:3:29: error: invalid template-id
    3 | constexpr auto f(auto x) -> s<x> { return {}; }
      |                             ^
<source>:3:32: error: use of parameter outside function body before '>' token
    3 | constexpr auto f(auto x) -> s<x> { return {}; }
      |                                ^
<source>:3:11: error: deduced class type 's' in function return type
    3 | constexpr auto f(auto x) -> s<x> { return {}; }
      |           ^~~~
<source>:2:8: note: 'template<bool B> struct s' declared here
    2 | struct s { constexpr operator bool() const { return B; } };
      |        ^
<source>:4:15: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
    4 | static_assert(f(s<true>{}));
      |               ^
```

The error message from MSVC:

```
<source>(4): error C2440: 'static_assert': cannot convert from 's<x>' to 'bool'
<source>(4): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform
this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: Remove the trailing return type and do `return s<x>{};` inside the function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a workaround that shouldn't be taken lightly, as it comes with a cost that's not always acceptable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tnl7FnwJ2Uw&t=2583s

Comment: Do you mean the cost of clarity? Well, using deduced return types where it's obvious what the type will be isn't such a high cost for making it work. In this case it's really obvious so there's not much of a loss of clarity. In really complicated functions I sometimes typedef the types of interest. The first line in your function could be `using return_type = s<x>;` to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

According to [a comment by a GCC maintainer](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104255#c2), gcc is motivated to reject by [a Note to [basic.scope.param]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.param#note-1):

> [*Note 1*: A function parameter cannot be used for its value within the *parameter-declaration-clause* ([dcl.fct.default]). — *end note*]

However, you are not using the parameter for its value (the conversion operator does not access the class object) so this Note is irrelevant (as well as, of course, being non-normative). There is no other reason to reject, so per [[expr.const]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5) the code should be accepted.

If you change the declaration of `f` to:

```cpp
constexpr auto f(auto x) -> decltype([](auto y) { return s<y>(); }(x)) { return {}; }
```

then gcc and MSVC accept, but clang rejects.

Comment: Which specific text of the standardese allows the use of `[](auto x) -> decltype(+std::get<x>(std::array{0})) { return {}; }(std::bool_constant<true>{});`? The part of interest being where `x`'s member-function `constexpr operator bool() const` is invoked without needing an actual `std::bool_constant` object to operate on.

Comment: @303 expr.const/5: "An expression E is a core constant expression unless [...]" and [Example 5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#example-5) to expr.const/8.